# using capistrano on a shared host, how to set the temporary directory for repo access

Tags: capistrano

cap is trying to create this location on my server to access my git repo (on bitbucket). Unfortunately this is a shared host, and the ssh keys are in my user directory, not in /tmp…. so this fails:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/doman.com/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote
```

Can I configure this tmp dir to be in my home dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Capistrano Github page](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) you should set the **:tmp_dir** variable to a directory on your homepath like **/home/user/tmp/capistrano**

For example:

```
set :tmp_dir, '/home/user/tmp/capistrano'
```